# ValueError: time data does not match format '%HH:%MM:%SS' when subtracting two time strings

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x

I am trying to find the difference between two time strings with the following python code.

```
print('time base one {}'.format(time_base_day_one))
s1 = '24:00:00'
s2 = time_base_day_one
FMT = '%HH:%MM:%SS'

print('type of time_base_day_one {} type of s1 {}'.format(type(time_base_day_one),type(s1)))
time_offset_day_two = datetime.strptime(s2, FMT) - datetime.strptime(s1, FMT)
```

I am getting the following error.

```
ValueError: time data '11:00:19' does not match format '%HH:%MM:%SS'
```

Comment: your tokens are wrong. note that %H` matches for 2 numbers, so does `%M` and  `%S`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format `FMT` should be `'%H:%M:%S'`. Here's a link to the specifications for `strftime/strptime` https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: in that case I get this error - `ValueError: time data '24:00:00' does not match format '%H:%M:%S`

Comment: @liv2hak That's because 24:00:00 isn't a valid time it should be 00:00:00 instead.